# All babies are querulous. But David is not a baby, so he is not querulous

Tags: logic, fallacies

Does the following argument involve a fallacy?

All babies are querulous. But David is not a baby, so he is not querulous.

(a) undistributed middle

(b) denying the antecedent

(c) affirming the consequent

(d) no fallacy; deductively valid

Comment: From previous readings, denying the antecedent would be "if this, then that. But not this, so that"                                                                                              In this :   P1- All babies are querulous.     P2-  David is not a baby.              C- So, David is not querulous. Therefore B, is seemingly the fallacy.

Comment: You're right, this is indeed denying the antecedent.

Comment: If the question were altered to : " All babies are querulous. David is not querulous, so he is not a baby" Is it the variant: affirming the consequent ? @commando

Comment: We can look forward to much more site traffic in the coming weeks/months if you're going to post every homework question this term :)

Comment: Would this be such a bad thing @Keelan ? More input and feedback to questions each and every individual has, broadening ones knowledge? Sorry if you are frustrated! I beg my pardon for asking for help!

Comment: For us it is not a bad thing, and if people get frustrated (not me) they can always ignore the questions. Whether it is an efficient study methods is for you to find out / decide.

Comment: I find this the most useful study mode. I struggle with philosophy myself and for me this is a way to see different perspectives and understand why people view the questions the way they do. Sorry if I have taken your time and efforts, i really appreciate the layout of feedback and information that has been given to my questions. It has thoroughly improved my understanding of the subject. @Keelan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the given argument involves a formal fallacy, [denying the antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent), which goes like this:

> 1. p → q
> 2. ~p
> 3. Therefore, ~q

The conclusion doesn't logically follow from the premises.

The given argument is clearly an instance of that:

> 1. ∀x(Bx → Qx) [all babies are querulous]
> 2. ~Bd [David is not a baby]
> 3. Therefore, ~Qd [David is not querulus]